# Loopback remote method relation List to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I'm building custom remote methods to Loopback. When I'm doing query and trying to forward relations to own function where is forEach. Realtion list causes error `relations.forEach is not a function`

Example:

```
return Api.find({include: ['relations']}).then(result => {
    return myFunction(result.relations)
})

myFunction(relations) {relations.forEach(obj => {console.log(obj)})};
```

How I can convert List object to javascript array. toJSON() not working for List objects

Comment: Please define "_JSON array_".

Comment: I mean List(this is Loopbacks own javascript class) object to JSON Array presentation, like [{name: "name", id: "id" etc...}]

Comment: What you want is just an array of objects, there's no such thing as "_JSON array_" in JS.

Comment: thats true, my mistake, but I mean array of objects

Comment: How exactly the passed object (`result.relations`) looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to do the JSON conversion directly on your result? Like:

```
return Api.find({include: ['relations']}).then(result => {
    result = result.toJSON(); //add this line
    return myFunction(result.relations)
})

myFunction(relations) {relations.forEach(obj => {console.log(obj)})};
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need json string from an array of objects, then:

```js
var jsonString=JSON.stringify({relations:relations});
```

Comment: This dosen't work for the Loopbacks List object. I will get parse errors, when converting it.

Comment: Maybe you should simplify the loopBacks object before converting.

Answer (score 0):

try to call `result.relations()` to get the array